# App Downloads from web link

Tags: ios, web, app-store

I would like to be able to track how many people download my iOS app by being directed to the App Store from my website compared to just searching the App Store. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

http://analytics.itunes.apple.com should help you.

There you can track the referrals to your app and one of the referrals is your website ;)